# How to measure resistance of a gel electrolyte using a multimeter

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, conductivity, electricity

How can I measure the resistance of a gel electrolyte using a multimeter? I know the formula to measure the conductivity of a gel electrolyte is k = (1/R) * (d/a)

where k is the conductivity (S/cm), R is the resistance (of the electrolyte), d is the distance between the two electrodes, and a is the effective area of the electrodes.

I wanted to measure the conductivity of the gel electrolyte with just a multimeter. Since this is a gel electrolyte, I was thinking to substitute the thickness of the gel electrolyte as d and substitute the area of the gel electrolyte as a. (I know the area (a) has to be that of the electrodes, but I want to measure the conductivity of the gel electrolyte without the electrodes). So now all that remains is the resistance of the gel electrolyte. To do this can I just measure its resistance using a multimeter?

(I understand that you have to use two similar electrodes sandwiched between the electrolyte in order to measure the conductivity of it, but is there a way around?)

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really seem to be about chemistry. It seems to be more suited to physics.SE as it's just about measuring electrical properties.